# Proving $X$ is a complete statistic to find a UMVUE

Tags: normal-distribution, umvue, complete-statistics

I'm learning about Stein's phenomenon. This standard problem is considered:

Let $X_1, \dots, X_p$ be independent random variables with $X_i \sim N(\theta_i, 1)$ for $i = 1, \dots, p$. Let $\theta = (\theta_1, \dots, \theta_p)$ and $X = (X_1, \dots, X_p)$. We wish to estimate $\theta$ under quadratic loss.

As part of the justification for first considering the "obvious" estimator, $\hat{\theta} = X$, it is noted without proof that $\hat{\theta}$ is the UMVUE for estimating $\theta$.

To show this, I think we wish to use the Lehmann-Scheffé theorem. Immediately, the estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is unbiased, and the statistic $X$ is sufficient for $\theta$.

How can one prove $X$ is a complete statistic for the underlying distribution in order to invoke the Lehmann-Scheffé Theorem please?

Many thanks

Comment: At present the q does not make sense, probably it is a typo. $X$ is a vector so canot be an estimator of $\theta$, which is a scalar! Please correct.

Comment: I believe $\theta$ is a vector? In the third line, I defined $\theta = (\theta_1, \dots, \theta_p)$.

Comment: Please note that the $X_i$ are not identically distributed. Each has its own mean, $\theta_i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completeness can be justified indirectly if you invoke results of the [Exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family).

The pdf of $X$ for $\theta\in\mathbb R^p$ is

\begin{align}
f_{\theta}(x)&=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^p}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^p (x_i-\theta_i)^2\right]
\\&=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^p}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}x^Tx-\frac{1}{2}\theta^T\theta+x^T\theta\right]\quad,\small x=(x_1,\ldots,x_p)\in\mathbb R^p
\end{align}

This density is a member of a full rank exponential family, which guarantees that a complete sufficient statistic for $\theta$ is $X^T$, or simply $X$.

---

I think completeness can also be proved in the following way. Let $g(\cdot)$ be any function of $x$.

Then, $$E_{\theta}[g(X)]=0\quad\forall\,\theta\implies \int_{\mathbb R^p}e^{x^T\theta}g(x)e^{-\frac12x^Tx}\,dx=0\quad\forall\,\theta$$

The above is a (multidimensional) [bilateral Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-sided_Laplace_transform) of $g(x)e^{-\frac12x^Tx}$, which implies $$g(x)e^{-\frac12x^Tx}=0\quad,\text{ a.e.}$$

That is, $$g(x)=0\quad,\text{ a.e.}$$

Comment: I can see that this density is a member of the exponential family. Which result justifies that $X^T$ is a complete sufficient statistic?

Comment: @JohnSmith The relevant result is Proposition 2.1 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=1HQmBKMgDaMC&lpg=PR1&pg=PA110#v=onepage&q&f=false), where exponential family is defined in [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=1HQmBKMgDaMC&lpg=PR1&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q&f=false) way.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will accept your answer in a few days, if no other answers are given - I would like to wait a little because it would be more useful for me to have a direct proof that does not require introducing a lot more machinery and then invoking results from that.

Comment: @JohnSmith Do not bother about accepting the answer. A direct proof would be great in any case.